# Ошибка сегментирования (стек памяти сброшен на диск) (С)

Tags: c

Что не так с кодом?

#

```
include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE_OF_ARRAY 20

int index_first_negative (int a[], int amountOfElements)
{
    int index;
    for(int i = 0; i < amountOfElements; i++){
        if (a[i] < 0){
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return (index);
}

int index_last_negative (int a[], int amountOfElements)
{
    int index =-1;
    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfElements; i++){
        if (a[i] < 0){
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return (index);
}

int multi_between_negative (int a[], int indexFirst, int indexLast)
{
 int product = 1;
 if (indexFirst == indexLast){
     product = a[indexFirst];
 }
 else{  
     for (indexFirst++; indexFirst <= indexLast; indexFirst++){
     product = product * a[indexFirst];
      }
     }
 return (product);
}

int multi_before_and_after_negative (int a[], int indexFirst, int indexLast, int amountOfElements)
{
    int product = 1; 
    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfElements; i++){
        if ( i == indexFirst){
            i = indexLast;
        }
    product = product * a[i];
    }
 return(product);
} 

int main(){   
    int a[SIZE_OF_ARRAY];
    int i = 0;
    int functioNumber = -1;
    int answer = -1;
    int indexFirst = -1;
    int indexLast = -1;
    int amountOfElements = 0;
    char c;

    for (i; i < SIZE_OF_ARRAY; i++){
        a[i] = 0;
    }
    scanf("%d ", &functioNumber);
    do{

        scanf("%d%c", &a[i], &c);
            i++;
            amountOfElements++;

    } while (c!='\n');
    switch (functioNumber)
    {
        case 0:
            answer = index_first_negative(a, amountOfElements);
            if (answer != -1){
                printf("%d\n", answer);

                }
                else{
                    printf("0000Нет отрицательных элементов\n");

                }
        case 1:
            answer = index_last_negative(a, amountOfElements);
            if (answer != -1){
                printf("%d\n", answer);

                }
                else{
                    printf("1111Нет отрицательных элементов\n");

                }
        case 2:
            indexFirst = index_first_negative(a, amountOfElements);
            indexLast = index_last_negative (a, amountOfElements);
            if (indexFirst == -1 && indexLast == -1){
                printf("2222Нет отрицательных элементов\n");

            }
            else{
                answer = multi_between_negative(a, indexFirst, indexLast);
                printf("%d\n", answer);

                }
        case 3:
            indexFirst = index_first_negative(a, amountOfElements);
            indexLast = index_last_negative (a, amountOfElements);
            if (indexFirst == -1 && indexLast == -1){
                printf("3333Нет отрицательных элементов\n");

            }
            else{
                answer = multi_before_and_after_negative(a, indexFirst, indexLast, amountOfElements);
                printf("%d\n", answer);

            }
        default :
            printf("Функции %d не существуе\n", functioNumber);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Откуда возник такой вопрос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вначале посмотрите, что делает `index_first_negative`, если отрицательных элементов нет - она возвратит мусор.

Дальше посмотрите на этот участок кода (с моими комментариями)

```
// что здесь делает просто i в первой части for? оно бессмыслено
for (i; i < SIZE_OF_ARRAY; i++){
    a[i] = 0;
}
scanf("%d ", &functioNumber);
do{
    // а здесь i точно уже за пределами массива.
    // может перед do нужно было занулить?
    scanf("%d%c", &a[i], &c);

        i++;
        amountOfElements++;

} while (c!='\n');
```

Еще дальше. Там идет большой switch, но вот break  в нем нет. А это приведет к "проваливанию" со всеми вытекающими последствиями.

Дальше уже нет смысла анализировать. В коде явно отсутствует такое понятие, как инициализация переменных.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Для профиля: «в разрез» пишется слитно :)